# Отправить файл JS Fetch -> WebAPI

Tags: javascript, c#, fetch, webapi

Всем привет, пытаюсь отправить из js(Fetch API) файл в ASP .NET Core Web API, но получаю ошибку 400, если удалить заголовки то 415. Пытался отправить только файл, без обертки в FormData, аналогичный результат, 400 и 415 если без заголовков. В чем проблема?

JS код:

```
let data = new FormData()
data.append('file', file)
const response = await fetch('https://localhost:7054/Pictures',
{
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
         'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
    },
    body: data
});
```

Метод контроллера:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> Index([FromBody]IFormFile file)
{
    try
    {
        using (var fs = new FileStream(dir, FileMode.Create))
        {
             await file.CopyToAsync(fs);
        }
        return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status201Created);
    }
    catch
    {
        return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError);
    }
}
```

Comment: Что содержит `file`?

Comment: У вас в js коде `;` отсутствуют, он по идее не рабочий, как вы 400 из него получили, если он должен упасть раньше, чем сработает fetch?

Comment: file - изображение любого формата, про `;` не совсем понял, они же ни на что не влияют в js

Comment: `они же ни на что не влияют в js` во всех браузерах? https://stackoverflow.com/a/8108912/12888024